# IPhone Time Difference Issue

Tags: ios, timer

I am implementing a tableview with cells displaying a timer. Actually its a difference between server time and current phone time.But if the phone time is wrong the timer value also goes wrong.Any Fix for the same .Any method by which we can implement the timer without relying on phone's time?

Comment: Will you please elaborate the functionality you want to implement ? like what timer do is it like stop watch ?(which start from 00:30 and go to 00:00) OR it is display time which is remaining for target time? (like 00:30 minit remaining for 12:00)

Comment: Its displaying time differnce.

Comment: Time difference between device time and server time ?

Comment: ya actually its a call queue and i am displaying the time since the call was placed.The time of calling is what we get from server .

Comment: there is only one solution i found, first when you ask for call placed time to server, also ask for time sliced and then run your own timer logic to increase time value.